# Push Notification on google calendar

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, google-calendar-api

I have a WCF Service and and an Website(say www.GoogleNotificationCallback.com) to receive Google Push notification from Google calenders.

Whenever some event is updated/Deleted/Added on Google calendar, it sends back an notification to my Endpoint(www.GoogleNotificationCallback.com)

To manage the load for incoming requests from google calender for push notification, I have load balancing servers on which I have my website(www.GoogleNotificationCallback.com) and `WCF service hosted.`

Every thing is working fine, but the issue is, if I `create/Update/Delete/Move` any Event on Google Calendar it sends back multiple hits to the endpoint(www.GoogleNotificationCallback.com).

I checked for ChannelId, MessageId and CalendarId from the current Context.

```
{var context = HttpContext.Current;

 string reqheaders = "reached";

 var actualRequest = context.Request;

 var reqKeys = context.Request.Headers.AllKeys;}
```

But for each current context.Request I am getting same CalenderId but different ChannelId and MessageId.

I am not able to understand why Google is creating multiple channels for an single change ? OR why it is giving multiple push notifications to my end point (www.GoogleNotificationCallback.com)?

Is there any settings that i am missing or via coding i am doing any mistake.
can any one please guide me for the same?

Comment: That isn't enough code to recreate your problem.  please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have an issue that whenever I Create/Move/Delete event from google calendar ,my website gets hit by google calendar ,so here it goes to Pageload of my website(lets say Default.aspx),so google calendar hits my website's Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) multiple times for a single click on calendar events. so these are the lines of code that is  @DalmTo

Comment: written over my page load                                                                  '{var context = HttpContext.Current;
 string reqheaders = "reached";
 var actualRequest = context.Request;
 var reqKeys = context.Request.Headers.AllKeys;}'